# .NET Core 3.0 Blazor app Windows Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I've got a Blazor server-side app using Windows Authentication that is not working from a published build.  When I go to access the site normally, Chrome (and IE) prompt me for a username and password.  After I enter my credentials and click Sign In, it just refreshes the prompt and asks me for it again.

I'm not running into this issue when I start the site from Visual Studio with IISExpress to debug the site.  When the app launches it takes me right in.

Is this behavior supposed to be what I'm seeing in a production build?

**UPDATE**

Some additional information:

```
ApplicationPool:
  - .NET CLR Version: No Managed Code
  - Managed Pipeline: Integrated
  - Identity: NetworkService

Site:
  - Authentication Rules
      - Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
      - Basic Authentication: Disabled, Response Type: HTTP 401 Challenge
      - Digest Authentication: Disabled, Response Type: HTTP 401 Challenge
      - Windows Authentication: Enabled, Response Type: HTTP 401 Challenge

ASP .NET Core App:
  - Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
  - Windows Authentication: Enabled

Environment:
  - IIS Server is on computer that is part of the domain
  - AD User is logged in to computer
```

Comment: More input please. Where do you host the application? IIS? Just so on Windows? Linux?

Comment: @Tseng - It's hosted on IIS, currently on my own dev pc.  I can post the Publish profile if that will help.

Comment: I did a test with my Blazor server-side app, can not reproduce same issue on my side. Please clarify more about steps that you took to configure Windows Authentication, so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: @FeiHan - I have updated my question to have some additional info about my IIS setup, my app, and my environment that I am hosting this on.